# Requests interacting strangely with redirect

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to write a little scraper to extract finisher results for a marathon listed on marathonguide.com, having trouble getting redirect to display correct page.

Navigation on the site is simple enough:

- **Event** page: http://www.marathonguide.com/results/browse.cfm?MIDD=472131103
- Form POST (example): Gen='B', Begin=201, End=300, Max=50062
- POST URL: http://www.marathonguide.com/results/makelinks.cfm
- **Results** page: http://www.marathonguide.com/results/browse.cfm?MIDD=472131103&Gen=B&Begin=201&End=300&Max=50062

This Results page only displays finisher data when I follow the standard form submit navigation. If I refresh this page, however, or type the URL in directly the URL will reflect the Results page but display the *Event Page*.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

marathon = 'http://www.marathonguide.com/results/browse.cfm?MIDD=472131103'

s = requests.session()
p = s.get(marathon)

race_range = 'B,201,300,50062'
rp = 'http://www.marathonguide.com/results/makelinks.cfm'
data = {'RaceRange':race_range, 'RaceRange_Required':'You must make a selection before viewing results.', 'MIDD':'472131103', 'SubmitButton':'View'}

results = s.post(rp, data=data)

print results.status_code
print results.url    
print results.text

>>> 200
>>> http://www.marathonguide.com/results/browse.cfm?MIDD=472131103&Gen=B&Begin=201&End=300&Max=50062
>>> HTML from http://www.marathonguide.com/results/browse.cfm?MIDD=472131103
```

Based on the HTML I'm getting I'm being sent back to the Event page, wondering why the server doesn't like my POST. Debating using selenium to just mimic the user experience, but I'm sure there's something minor missing from my Requests code.

**Edit:** based on feedback I've updated the question to reflect my actual code.

Comment: Sharing the URL is allowed in SO. Just take care, though, if this is proprietary code you're writing (for your company, as an example) or if the site is a private network (for which you're opening it up to external access). Otherwise, it's pretty safe. Tons of URLs are shared all the time. That said, I suppose it's better if you share it so we can inspect it. :)

Comment: Thanks @Nanashi, have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, posting an answer in a while. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're being directed back to the events page is because this particular POST request requires a referral. This means that if it is accessed directly, without it coming from the expected URL, it's not going to process your request. This can thwart simple form data POST actions as well as string manipulation.

A simple test to see if this is in the page: Try going to the results page right away. What happens? Pretty much nothing because you are directed back to the events page with the respective MIDD. Even if you try manipulating the string, it won't work.

The way to get around this is to find the URL that refers. You can do this by checking the headers and looking for a `Referer` key. See below screenshot.

[image]

We then get this value and incorporate into our POST request. Following is your code, modified to accommodate the aforementioned action.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

marathon = 'http://www.marathonguide.com/results/browse.cfm?MIDD=472131103'

s = requests.session()
p = s.get(marathon)

race_range = 'M,201,300,50062'
rp = 'http://www.marathonguide.com/results/makelinks.cfm'
data = {'RaceRange':race_range, 'RaceRange_Required':'You must make a selection before viewing results.', 'MIDD':'472131103', 'SubmitButton':'View'}
headers = {
"Referer":"http://www.marathonguide.com/results/browse.cfm?MIDD=472131103",
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"
}

results = s.post(rp, data=data, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content)

rows = soup.find_all("tr", {"bgcolor":"#CCCCCC"})
for row in rows:
  print row.find("td").get_text()
```

Pay attention to the `headers` line as well as the new `results = s.post...` line. Also, notice that the proper gender value is not `B` but `M`. Check `race_range` line to see what I mean.

Finally, the result is as follows:

```
JAKOB SKOTT (M37)
MATIAS MARQUEZ (M44)
JOSE ESPINOSA (M33)
MATTHEW BERGENHOLTZ (M32)
MICHAEL KNAK (M33)
NICK BEDBURY (M25)
BOB LARUE (M29)
JONATAN TROLDBORG (M19)
PEDER TROLDBORG (M50)
FRANCOIS LHUISSIER (M35)
PETER KRIEGER (M34)
ANDREW YIM (M42)
CRISTIAN VALENZUELA (M27)
MARCO CAVALLUCCI (M46)
JONATHAN DROUT (M41)
SVEN WISSING (M35)
JIM CLEMENS (M46)
YVES SCHINDFESSEL (M47)
JASON BROWN (M37)
ULRICH FLUHME (M39)
MICHAEL ALBERT (M43)
JOSE LUIS BENITEZ (M29)
NATHAN AHART (M26)
LAWRENCE WARRINER (M50)
LUIS DIAS (M46)
MARIO DIMAS (M31)
RICARDO VALE (M25)
CHRIS FISHER (M35)
JOON SONG (M43)
CIARAN CANAVAN (M39)
LEIF WELHAVEN (M40)
TOM PAPAIN (M26)
NIELS DECLERCK (M26)
PHIL TEIJEIRA (M35)
JAN MUENCH (M39)
FILIPPO DE CONTO (M36)
PETER TOLLEFSON (M32)
MORTEN JEST (M40)
DOUGLAS LETTERMAN (M34)
JENS RITTER (M41)
PAUL BURTON (M50)
JOSE AGUETE (M34)
PAUL ROOME (M40)
GLEN WEISSMAN (M44)
CLIFF GERBER (M28)
JON FIVA (M35)
TODD BLANCHARD (M44)
CHRISTOPHE TREUIL (M41)
BRUNO RAINAUD (M45)
JACOB LEBLANC (M29)
[Finished in 4.1s]
```

Which matches the results in the page itself, viewed in the browser:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Nanashi, this did the trick. Thanks a ton. Unbelievable--I definitely noticed the Referer in the Request Headers but thought the `requests.session()` was carrying this through!

Comment: One minor note--the `B` is actually correct. It returns results for both men and women. The `M` returns only men.